# Can't select component declared in a template for Angular 2 using @ViewChildren

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm migrating a jQuery application to Angular 2 and one of the passages that didn't work is the following selector for setting a behavior of the menus.

```
$("li.dropdown").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function () { ... });
```

My strategy was to refer to it using `@ViewChildren` and set the behavior in `ngOnInit` method or, if necessary, in the `ngAfterContentInit` method. However, it seems that when I hit the breakpoint and type `this.comboxes` in the console, the list `undefined`. I've googled around but didn't really hit anything useful (might be my ignorance to be blamed, though).

How can I go about to set a mousy behavior to some of the elements in the template? I'm fully open to another approach if this one is flawed.

```
import { Component, ViewChildren } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "navbar",
  template: require("./navbar.html")
})
export class NavBar {
  @ViewChildren("li.dropdown") comboxes;

  constructor() { console.log("NavBar created"); }

  ngOnInit() { console.log("OnInit"); debugger; }

  ngAfterContentInit() { console.log("OnCompInit"); debugger; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selector used by `@ViewChildren` is not the same as JQuery uses:

> Specifies a CSS selector that identifies this directive within a template. Supported selectors include element, [attribute], .class, and :not().
>
> Does not support parent-child relationship selectors.

Also `@ViewChildren` by default will find only components and directives with matching selectors. You need to pass template reference to `@ViewChildren` to query for DOM:

```
<div #templateRef>test</div>
<component #templateRef></component>

@ViewChildren('templateRef', {read: ElementRef}) nodes:QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how to proceed. My template `require`s a file from the directory. Are you saying that I need to set an ID to each component that I'm going to be referring to in my customizational script?

Comment: Yes, it is called template reference, see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars

Comment: Interesting. Not quite there yet, though. I've got now `<div #templateRef class="row">` in my template and I put in the precise like as you suggested. However, when I breakpoint in `ngAfterContentInit` I still get `undefined`. What else might be wrong? +1 for the great link.

Comment: You should use `AfterViewInit` instead of `AfterContentInit`.

Comment: There's something in the `nodes` variable to the issue as asked is resolve. However, I'm having the impression that I'm doing it all wrong (which usually manifests in everything being difficult and complicated). Now, for instance, I can't access the simple HTML component inside `nodes` to hang some events on the menus. I've seen something about converters or something and I'm starting to feel that I'm barking the wrong DOM-tree... What do you think?

Comment: Native/HTML elements are wrapped into `ElementRef`  classes by design, QueryList is dynamic list... I think you should go through couple of guides on angular.io to learn basic approaches.